# leftJoinAndSelect in nestJs does not retrieve all data from postgresql

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have three tables `product`, `branch` and `product_branches`

product table contains: `id, name`

branch table contains: `id, name, lat, lng`

product_branches table contains: `productId, branchId`

I have this query

```
const query = this.createQueryBuilder('products')
  .leftJoin('products.productBranches', 'productBranches')
  .leftJoinAndSelect(
    'branch',
    'branches',
    'productBranches.branchId = branches.id',
  );


const products = await query.getMany();
```

the result appear like this

```
[
{
    "id": "143f6e35-59ae-4185-bed2-a479ec716489",
    "name": "product name",
},
.....]
```

but the result must be like this

```
[
{
    "id": "143f6e35-59ae-4185-bed2-a479ec716489",
    "name": "product name",
    "branches": [
       {
           "id": "143f6e35-59ae-4185-bed2-a479ec716489",
           "name": "branch name",
           "lat": "lat",
           "lng": "lng",
       },
       ....
    ]
},
....]
```

when I log the query `console.log('query: ${query.getQuery()}');` and copy the result to **postgresql**, the query works fine and return the data

here is my entities:

```
@Entity()
export class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @OneToMany((_type) => ProductBranches, (productBranches) => productBranches.product, {
    eager: false,
  })
  productBranches: ProductBranches[];
}

@Entity()
export class Branch {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  lat: string;

  @Column()
  lng: string;

  @OneToMany((_type) => ProductBranches, (productBranches) => productBranches.branch, { eager: false, },)
  productBranches: ProductBranches[];
}

@Entity()
export class ProductBranches {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @ManyToOne((_type) => Product, (product) => product.productBranches, {
    eager: true,
  })
  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  product: string;

  @ManyToOne((_type) => Branch, (branch) => branch.productBranches, {
    eager: true,
  })
  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  branch: string;
}
```

Note: I tried `find` with relations

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is separated to two sides

1. `@Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })` on the `branch: string;` in `ProductBranches Entity`
2. using `createQueryBuilder` is not right in this situation, instead use

   ```
   const offers = this.find({
      relations: ['productBranches'],
   });
   ```

but the `branch` will be inside the `productBranches` not in a separate JSON object

Thanks to my friend Mohammad Ali